# Error: assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

**What I want to achieve:** I wish to split the input and put it into different arrays. 
Example:

```
The user enters: 1337 Hello World
//Programs split input and store 1337 in str1 and Hello World in str2
```

I have a code that creates this error:

> `main.c:19:12: error: assignment to expression with array type`
>
> ```
> str2[i] = strtok(NULL, "\n");
>         ^
> ```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char input[1000], str1[100][1000], str2[100][1000];
    int i;

    for(;; i++){
        printf("Enter a day and remainder: ");
        gets(input);

        if(strcmp(input, "0") == 0)
            break;
        else{
            str1[i] = strtok(input," ");//The cause of the error
            str2[i] = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I have done my research regarding this error. From what I learned, you can't assign an array to a var, but that isn't what I am trying to do. I'm assigning an array value to an array. 
The problem I believe is in the `strtok` function because I believe it serves as a char value. What I am thinking of doing is splitting the input and putting it into different var and then putting it into an array, but that isn't efficient.

**P.S:** I know I will get a comment saying don't use `gets()`, use `fgets()` to prevent overflow. I recommend you don't put that comment. I have to use due to my teacher but will change later for my use.

Comment: Use `strcpy` (or such as) instead of `=`.

Comment: But I wish to split the input and put it into different arrays. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: There's uininitalized variable in there. Perhaps, read the manual page about `strtok` and look at what it returns? As for `fgets` and `gets`, using that comment in there, contradictory don't you think considering you have bugs in the code.

Comment: @t0mm13b Where is the uininitalized? variable

Comment: variable `i` is uninitialized..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I declared `i` as an `int`. Also how would I use `strcpy` in this case

Comment: `int i;` --> `int i = 0;`, `str1[i] = strtok(input," ");` --> `strcpy(str1[i], strtok(input," "));`

Comment: Declaring a variable is not the same as initializing it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That worked thank you

Comment: @SiggiSv I now know that. Thank you.

Comment: "you can't assign an array to a var" You can assign an array to a pointer but you can neither assign a pointer to an array nor an array to an array (you can assign a pointer into an array of pointers but that's a different thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code was not initializing `i` and `strtok`. I assumed that when declaring a var, it will have a value of 0. That was one mistake and using `strtok` like that isn't right because you can't assign an array to an array. You should use `strcpy` instead and you will achieve the same result.

Comment: You got it almost right. `strtok()` returns a pointer to char, that can not be assigned to an array of char.